# Joining Multiple Datasets in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I'm just wondering if there is any way to join data within Amazon Quicksight. I have several data sets each created from a separate database. I was wondering if there is any way to join these data sets together.

Thanks

Comment: Does the way from the official docs solve your task https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/joining-tables.html ?

Comment: That seems to only allow joining data from a single data source.

Comment: You can join now datasets from two diff data sources - inside of the Dataset itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of May 2019, there is not a way to join datasets from different databases or different schemas hosted in the same database.

A few options to consider that I have done to work around this:

1) If your data sources are all hosted in same database but are from different schemas, you could create a view in the database that joins the data there and then pull the data from the view

2) Use the [DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) service to move your data all into the same spot.  We ended up creating a datalake (i.e. S3 bucket) where we used DMS to dump a nightly snapshot of our RDS database tables from different schemas into S3.  We then also have other processes that put emailed reports and other streams of data into S3. Once everything is in S3, you can use [Glue Crawlers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-crawlers.html) to put the S3 data into a catalog which can then be imported into QuickSight via Athena tables.

Comment: As of November 2019 - https://idk.dev/joining-across-data-sources-on-amazon-quicksight/

Comment: **As of Jun 2020**: Still the documentation says - "Each visual can use only one data set." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-data-set-to-an-analysis.html) @MillerC I think the question pertains to joining two datasets, and not two data sources (your links talks about latter).